# Where is the `context.become` implemented?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

Akka 2.3.11 has a `trait ActorContext` with methods

```
def become(behavior: Actor.Receive): Unit = become(behavior, discardOld = true)
def become(behavior: Actor.Receive, discardOld: Boolean): Unit
```

However, it is only a declaration. I am looking for an actual implementation and am unable to find it. Even IntelliJ does not help with it's feature "Jump to implementation" as it only jumps to this declaration.

I am aware what the `context.become` does in an Actor, but I am curious how it is implemented. Where can I find this implementation?

As a part of the answer I expect an explanation of the process of searching for this implementation and why IntelliJ jumps only to the declaration.

Comment: You need to know what the concrete type of `ActorContext` is that's being used in the running actor system.  Figure that out and you will have your answer on where to look for the code impl.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation is in `akka.actor.ActorCell`, in the same source file as `ActorContext`.

IntelliJ seems to have some trouble finding this implementation, probably because `ActorCell` is `private[akka]`.